# bootstrap-responsive - how to redefine / overwrite a css class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

**Background Info**

I'm trying my hand at my first responsive app using bootstrap.  So far, so good.  But I'm trying to target the google nexus 7 and by default, it seems to be classified as a "phone" based on the following css I see in bootstrap-responsive.css:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .visible-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .visible-phone {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .hidden-phone {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

In one of pages, I have the following logic:

```
 <div class="row-fluid visible-desktop">                      
         some html here for desktop version only
         display big buttons
 </div>

 <div class="row-fluid visible-tablet">                   
         some html here for ipads
         display medium buttons
 </div>

 <div class="row-fluid visible-phone">                    
         display divs, not buttons.
 </div>
```

**Problem**

Currently, the nexus 7 in portrait mode is picking up the section for the phones, and I can't understand why?
The other question I have is how to overwrite or redefine bootstrap's "phone" media query in my own custom css?  (Please see notes below to understand what I've tried so far)

**What I've Tried So Far:**

As a test, I went to resizemybrowser.com using the nexus and it says that the Current Inner is 980x1294 when in portrait mode.  I guess I don't understand why the nexus diplays my phone section if the size is really that high?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the information displayed by the resizemybrowser.com website.

I've also been playing around with my custom.css and have found a browser size that seems to correctly target the nexus for me:

```
/* Google Nexus 7 Portrait */
@media (min-width:500px) and (max-width: 720px) and (orientation:portrait){
    body{
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

I'm testing with a nexus 7, ipod 5, iPad and a Samsung galaxy 3 and with the above media query, the only device that picks up the green background is the nexus... which is what I want. So i was thinking that I could redefine the media query in bootstrap-responsive to look like this: (basically just changing the max size of the browser from 767 to 500px).

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .visible-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .visible-phone {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .hidden-phone {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

The idea is to define a smaller browser size for phones...And then I would create a new media query that would target mini tablets.
But it seems that by creating the above media query in my custom.css doesn't replace / overwrite the one in bootstrap.  I don't want to change the code in bootstrap directly. 
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

This is how I'm loading the two css files:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">     

  <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/custom.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Is the google next media css below the phone css?

Comment: Charles380, yes the google nexus is the last css stuff I've defined in the file...does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and i think it's being forced styled through bootstrap js not css, because i'm able to override most of other css like buttons, carousel...etc
and sorry, but i haven't found any solutions for that yet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing everything correctly.

The problem is that your CSS file is being called BEFORE the bootstrap file and that is why it is not taking precedence over it.

Move your custom stylesheet to the bottom of your header and see if that gives your stylesheet priority over others.

Comment: avalera, I am loading my custom sheet afterwards... please check out section EDIT 1 in my post... thanks!

Comment: hmm... Do you have this live?

Comment: I'm not sure then. If it's being called last then it should overwrite the other stylesheets.